# How to solve Index Error in recursive function?

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have some problems when I write the recursive function.

The problem is finding the maximum total value in binary tree.

And each node can choose maximum child node.

For example, Node 8 can choose 1 and 0, then add 1.

[image: maximum total value]

My code is here,

```
triangle = [[7], [3, 8], [8, 1, 0], [2, 7, 4, 4], [4, 5, 2, 6, 5]]
#result = 30
depth = 1
answer = triangle[0][0] # depth : 0
total = 0

N1,N2 = triangle[1][0], triangle[1][1]
```

And, I write Recursive Functions like this,

```
def min_max(depth, N, total):
    if depth == len(triangle):
        return total
    else:
        a,b = triangle[depth+1][triangle[depth].index(N)], triangle[depth+1][triangle[depth].index(N)+1]
        total += max(a,b)
        N = max(a,b)
        return min_max(depth+1, N, total)
```

```
min_max(depth, N1, total)
```

But, I got list index out of range.

How can I fix recursive function?

Comment: Just add a in the if condition `if depth+1 == len(triangle)` and you will not crash, but not sure if other logic is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. When you write the binary tree into python list, depth becomes
>    index of the list. index of list always starts from 0 where as length
>    starts from 1.(i.e list of length 5 will be having indexes ranging
>    from 0 to 4)
>
> So, the starting depth should be equal to 0 and  the terminal
> condition of the recursive function should be `if depth+1 == len(triangle)`

Point 1 removes the index out of range issue. However we still have the problem with logic of code.

> 2. `total += max(a,b)` is checking for the maximum of the two number
>    where as it should be looking out for maximum value of two binary
>    tree.
>
> Above code will parse through the single line of data with maximum
> values and ignores rest of the possibilities.

[image]

Below is an alternate possibility to code.

```
def reduce(triangle: "list[list]"):
    print(triangle, flush=True)
    print('-----------------------------------', flush=True)
    if len(triangle) == 1:
        return triangle[0][0]
    else:
        last_line = triangle.pop()
        position = 0
        for value in triangle[-1]:
            value += max(last_line[position], last_line[position + 1])
            triangle[-1][position] = value
            position += 1
        return reduce(triangle)

print(reduce(triangle))
```

It works by removing the last line and adding maximum possible value to the second to last line each iteration until only one line remains

Output:

```
[[7], [3, 8], [8, 1, 0], [2, 7, 4, 4], [4, 5, 2, 6, 5]]
-----------------------------------
[[7], [3, 8], [8, 1, 0], [7, 12, 10, 10]]
-----------------------------------
[[7], [3, 8], [20, 13, 10]]
-----------------------------------
[[7], [23, 21]]
-----------------------------------
[[30]]
-----------------------------------
30
```